# How do I connect to a wireless network with clonezilla?

Tags: wireless-networking, backup, clonezilla

I want to back up a hard drive to my NAS with Clonezilla running from a thumb drive.

When I open up the application there is no option for connecting to a Wi-Fi that I can see. When I go into the command line and type `iw dev` it doesn't output anything. When I try to connect with DHCP via the menu system it will only try to conduct on eth0.

Downloaded Clonezilla today so it's a pretty current version.

Comment: I believe you have to click on Enter shell when clonezilla boots up and manually configure your wlan device. This will require some reading of documentation and example commands that have worked for others in the past. After your wlan device is installed and configured you then start clonezilla as normal and it should work.

Comment: if `iw dev` (which I found from reading blog posts etc) doesn't output anything I think reading blog posts and SU answers might not be enough